# How can I get the bean of a property file in Spring-Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

I need to play around keys of a property file. Key will be dynamic, so I need the bean of property file as mentioned below as my current running Spring application.

**Spring Configuration:**

```
<bean id="multipleWriterLocations" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:writerLocations.properties</value>
                <value>file:config/writerLocations.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**Java Code:**

```
Properties prop = appContext.getBean("multipleWriterLocations")
```

I need the same Properties bean instance in Spring-boot. I need to transform existing Spring application into Spring-Boot without changing the functionalities.

One way to get properties file value using @PropertySource(), but in this case I need the key name. But in my case, key name is not known and I need to fetch keySet from the Properties bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@ImportResource("classpath:config.xml")` where `config.xml` contains your `PropertiesFactoryBean` above, and then autowire it into your `@SpringBootApplication` or `@Configuration` class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:config.xml")
public class App {
    public App(PropertiesFactoryBean multipleWriterLocations) throws IOException {
        // Access the Properties populated from writerLocations.properties
        Properties properties = multipleWriterLocations.getObject();
        System.out.println(properties);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```